# react-native android app gives error , but iOS works

Tags: react-native, android-sdk-tools

i am new to react native

i followed the instructions on facebook react-native site to install java, Android Studio, SDK and SDK tools

the emulator is up and running , paths are correct. but when running the app i get

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
>   > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
>   >     javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema

the same app IOS runs , i even tried Android USB debugging

help please

anyone?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was Java 9. even though react-native site asks you to install Java SDK 8 or later , then 9 installation doesn't work for some reason. I uninstalled 9 and installed 8 and it worked like a charm

Comment: Great this Works! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This normally happens when the JDK is not correctly installed or the JAVA_HOME has not properly been set. Make sure to export your JAVA_HOME path. and have a working JDK version running on your computer.

Comment: my path is set, JAVA -version returns ' java version "9" '. I thought this was enough :-(